# Function equivalent to sprintf() with maximum number of characters to be copied?

Tags: c++, c

```
function(char* name)
{       
   char sql[50];
   sprintf(sql, "select %s;", name);
}
```

What's the best way to make sure only 50 chars of name are copied to sql in the case name is larger than what sql can hold? (sprintf with a N parameter?)

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `snprintf`, which also takes a size parameter:

```
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

`snprintf`, although it does not null terminate if you print N characters.

Comment: Actually, `snprintf` always does null-terminate the output.  `strncpy` is the function you need to watch out for.

Comment: Some older compilers (pre C99) did have the problem that did not null terminate if the buffer limit is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Most compilers have an snprintf() function.

Answer (score 1):

You want snprintf().

```
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```